# Performance impact of index datatype in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I need a new Mongo collection that associates data with an IP address, the address being the collection key. I'm wondering if there's any performance advantage using the decimal notation of the IP adress (e.g. `3299551096` as an integer) instead of the dotted notation (e.g. `"198.252.206.16"` as a string).

I haven't found any evidence for or against, nor any performance comparison between integer and string indexes. Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integer value storage requirement is smaller, but of course, not very significant. The sorting/indexing algorithm for a number would be **slightly** faster than a string normally, but the difference would be extremely small as the string is also very short.

I wouldn't expect a compelling performance difference between the two. If you're planning on storing IPV6 addresses, the issue will be that BSON (http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) doesn't have a simple data type for storing a 16-byte number, so it's not necessarily a natural fit to store as a number only.

In the end, I'd likely just use strings if you want to avoid doing translation from storage to screen, or if you want to make queries more natural to write for most of us :)  :

```
db.ips.find({addr: "192.168.1.1"})
```

If using strings, I'd also suggest you consider storing as a fixed format string such as `192.168.001.001` if you want to do more complex searches, such as a range search. Since a string stored with a consistent fixed format will sort naturally, you can use it in more ways than you'd otherwise be able to. If ranges aren't important, it's not necessary to store this way.

With a fixed format, you could do a query like:

```
db.ips.find({ addr: {
                 $gte: "192.168.000.000",
                 $lte: "192.168.000.255" } })
```

That would find all IP addresses between (inclusive) `192.168.0.0` and `192.168.0.255`.

Ideally, you'll have an index on the field either way:

```
db.ips.ensureIndex({ addr: 1 })
```

Comment: one difference can be in the queries, it is easier to do a range search on a int than a string

Comment: Would it? Why? Nothing comes to mind if the addresses are stored consistently. Maybe that's the issue. It should be  `###.###.###.###`.

Comment: The string format normally means you need to use regexs, that's what came to mind for me

Comment: Thanks -- I added a comment about the fixed format. I wouldn't expect a regex would be needed in most cases.

Comment: Let's go for a string index then. Hadn't thought about fixed format. I shouldn't need range queries, but you never know what will happen.