# Is it better to use number instead of string for enum schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is it better to use number instead of string for enum schema in mongoose in terms of search performance?

For example, I have this:

```
 status: {
     type: String, 
     enum: ['active', 'inactive', 'disabled', 'deleted'], 
     default: 'inactive'
 },

 //status: {
 //    type: Number, 
 //    enum: [0, 1, 2, 3], 
 //    default: '1'
 //},
```

will `db.col.find({status: 'active'})` slower than `db.col.find({status: 1})` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960817/performance-impact-of-index-datatype-in-mongodb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443228/enums-in-mongodb) similar questions it is for the most part negligible from a performance point of view when using an index - but numbers will be a bit faster.
In case you still want to use number, you could add a virtual property to your schema which translates from your numeric enum to a descriptive string so that you have the best of both worlds in some sense.

Answer (score 3):

Mongodb uses BSON(Binary JSON) to store the documents.
Read this for understanding json and bson Mongodb - https://www.mongodb.com/json-and-bson

Numbers (integers and doubles) are "basic types"
in BSON (the binary format in which data is stored in Mongo), and do
not carry the extra overhead with them.

Strings carry a little extra overhead with
them; bits to tell Mongo that they are strings, and bits to tell Mongo
how long they are.

So number would be faster than string.

**Reference**

http://bsonspec.org/spec.html