# MongoDB Indexes: String vs Int

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, indexing

New to Database management. I have a books database and I want to create an index for the ISBN which is 13 characters in length. Example: '9781509825889'

Currently I'm using a string index but I've read conflicting points on whether to store as an int or a string for indexing optimization.

It looks like I have Int32 or Int64 options and I think the above ISBN is too big for Int32 but is it worth switching to an Int64 for query optimization or should I just stick with string? Is there any significant performance gain?

Thanks

Comment: Here are some related / similar posts: (1) [Does field type matter in a MongoDB index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024362/does-field-type-matter-in-a-mongodb-index), (2) [Performance impact of index datatype in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960817/performance-impact-of-index-datatype-in-mongodb), and (3) [mongodb index data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994543/mongodb-index-data-structures/8995422#8995422).

Answer (score 7):

MongoDb indexes does not depends on the data type of the fields, so it does not matters you put it into `String` or `Int32` or `Int64`.

All indexes are hashed that's why it does not depends on the data type you used.

References:

1. [Does field type matter in a MongoDB index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024362/does-field-type-matter-in-a-mongodb-index)

Answer (score 6):

You have an option to create a `string` or a `long` (Int64). Int32 cannot accommodate the size.

The string data storage and index storage size will be slightly larger. For example, I created one million documents with number and string data types of isbn numbers  (in two different collections). The example document looked like this: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dc8d8fef25cf42fe848076d"), "isbn" : 1000000999999 }`. The `db.collection.stats()` shows the sizes information:

```
"size" : 36000000,
"count" : 1000000,
"avgObjSize" : 36,
"storageSize" : 12169216,
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 9920512,
        "isbn_1" : 10887168
},

"size" : 46000000,
"count" : 1000000,
"avgObjSize" : 46,
"storageSize" : 15015936,
"indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 9916416,
        "isbn_1" : 11018240
},
```

Also, noted the querying on isbn is equally fast, in general, irrespective of the datatype.

ISBNs are displayed as a structured number, e.g., `978-3-16-148410-0`. In case you are likely to use it in that format in the application, it can be stored as a structured string.